# How to add calendar item using MonoDroid?

Tags: calendar, xamarin.android

I'm trying to add an event to a calendar on an android device, and I'm using MonoDroid. I found the following example in Java: http://www.androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=3852

I tried to translate the first code snippet to C#, but I have trouble setting the "beginTime" and "endTime" fields, especially translating from Calendar.getTimeInMillis() to System.DateTime. This is my code:

```
DateTime epoch = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan startSpan = fromDate - epoch;
TimeSpan endSpan = toDate - epoch;

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionEdit);
intent.SetType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.PutExtra("beginTime", startSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
intent.PutExtra("endTime", endSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
```

The result is that the from and to fields are filled with today's date and a time slot with length of one hour.

How do I correctly set begin/end time of the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used a helper method in the past that has worked out pretty well. Here is a quick sample that should set the date and time properly.

```csh
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    AddEvent(this, "Sample Event", DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(5));
}

public void AddEvent(Context ctx, String title, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionEdit);
    intent.SetType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.PutExtra("title", title);
    intent.PutExtra("beginTime", TimeInMillis(start));
    intent.PutExtra("endTime", TimeInMillis(end));
    intent.PutExtra("allDay", false);
    ctx.StartActivity(intent);
}

private readonly static DateTime jan1970 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

private static Int64 TimeInMillis(DateTime dateTime)
{
    return (Int64)(dateTime - jan1970).TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works! My error was in calling PutExtra() with the result of DateTime.TotalMilliseconds, which returns double, not Int64.

Comment: I updated the sample code so that it can run standalone now. Previously, the TimeInMillis method was an extension method for datetime that would have caused some issues. Also, this code has only been tested for use in an Activity. If used in a fragment, etc. it will need modifications. Let me know if you are still having issues.

Comment: Mike, my code is identical to this, but when I call PutExtra with the MS the calendar comes up with the correct dates, but not the right time.  I put a breakpoint at TimeInMillis and both my dateTime and jan1970 are correct so I am assuming the msecs are correct.  But, my times come out wrong.

Comment: I am guessing that your times are not in UTC format. Make sure that if you are getting the current time, that you are using DateTime.UtcNow or if you have a DateTime object that you use the ToUniversalTime() method. Hopefully that will get everything set straight for you.

Comment: YES, you were correct it was UTC, so adding myDateTime.ToUniversalTime fixed most of the problem!  My End Time is always 1 hour from the start time.  Is "endTime" the correct PutExtra value?  Is there  duration value?  Or maybe I need to give it a timespan instead of the actually event end time?

Comment: LOL, ok, on my HTC phone android 2.3.3 the end time is always 1 hour from the start time.  But, on my Nexus Device, android 4.0.1 it works perfectly.  I am going to chalk it up to an htc/Android 2.3.3 bug.  Thanks for the help!!!